# Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war during installation

Tags: jenkins

While installing Jenkins I am getting an error `unable to access jarfile jenkins.war`. What could be causing this error?

There are also errors while attempting to install certain plugins.

Comment: My first guess would be you are seeing a permissions issue.  Also can you please provide some more information.  What OS are you installing Jenkins on, If on windows are you installing Jenkins as a service? At what point in the Jenkins install are you seeing the error.  Which plugins are you seeing failures for?

Comment: Ya Thanq Tuffwer. Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war" getting this error while run the cmd "java -jar jenkins.war" in OS- windows 7

How can I solve? i did installation as per what showed in youtube, how can i find jarfile ?

Comment: Check C:\Program FIles (x86)\Jenkins for the .war file.  That's the default install location. Youtube is a big place, I don't know which tutorial you were following.

Answer (score 1):

After I upgraded **jenkins**, the services would not restart. This is what I did:

1. Look at: **C:/Jenkins/jenkins.err.log**
2. Found in log file: **Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war**
3. It seems to have disappeared while upgrading
4. I went to: **https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/** and downloaded the war file from [permalink to the latest](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war) and copied it in **C:\Jenkins**
5. Restarted Jenkins services, waited 30 seconds and it was now working

Answer (score 0):

Extract the files and try the same command again.  It worked for me while doing so.